# Prometheus calculate delta and ignoring one label

Tags: prometheus

**First some data description:**

Name of the metric: query_seconds_count

example value:

```
query_seconds_count{correlation_id="someUUID",instance="someIp:Port",job="someJob",query_type="query",segment="overall"}
```

**What I want to do:**

```
delta(query_seconds_count[1m])
```

**The problem:**

The label `correlation_id` is unique for each query and therefore there is no chance to find a matching correlation id for calculating the delta. Delta is therefore always 0.
Is there any way to ignore the label `correlation_id` when calculating the delta?

I read about the keywords `ignoring`, `without`and `by`but it seems that they are not applicable to the delta function.

**possible workaround**

I could workaround the delta function using this but this doesn't look very elegant.

```
sum(query_seconds_count) without (correlation_id) - sum(query_seconds_count offset 1m) without (correlation_id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The label correlation_id is unique for each query and therefore there is no chance to find a matching correlation id for calculating the delta.

That's event logging, which Prometheus is not suited for at all as this is not a metric. You need to use a system such as ELK for this sort of data. If you wish to use Prometheus, you need to remove the correlation id in the client code.

In addition you should never use the `delta` function on counters. You probably want `increase`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Even though I think everything you said is correct, I won't mark this as correct answer since it is not answering the original question.

Comment: What you asked for is not possible, you can only fix this inside the client code.